# why my pages all items are little smaller in github website than my local web site?

Tags: github, project, display

I've done as much searching around on Google and on here as I possibly could before posting so please excuse me if this is easy to answer.

**My website's all items are smaller than my localhost website.** Please help me to fix this problem.
here is my repository link------ https://github.com/Amitgiri2001/portfolio/tree/master
please someone help me...

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your website, both locally and on https://amitgiri2001.github.io/Portfolio-Amit/, in order to see what are those "all items", and how they are smaller?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.